# to really addressing culture

Tags: word-usage

> “The cumulative effect of sexual harassment is extremely damaging,” says Paula Johnson, president of Wellesley College in Massachusetts and co-chair of the committee that wrote the report. “It’s critical to move beyond the notion of legal compliance **to really addressing culture**.”
> Source: Sexual harassment is rife in the sciences, finds landmark US study

[Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05404-6)

Does "addressing culture" refer to "addressing the culture of harassment in the sciences"? If so, shouldn't it be "addressing the culture" - with the article it would have particularly point to the bad culture.

Comment: I take it to mean 'the culture of academic life in the sciences which allows these things to happen'. I don't know why she didn't use _the_, but it's hardly a major error.

Answer (score 1):

She’s using the word not to refer to that particular culture, but to “culture” as a general *topic* that one can address.